# Rails validations for form wizard, best way to update step

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, validation

I have a form wizard that validates certain fields based on what the objects current step is. The problem I am having is that since the current_step is a part of the model, I cannot update the current_step without the validation failing. Let me show you what i mean.

## Model

```
class Goal< ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :school_id, if: 'current_step == "school"'
  validates_presence_of :class_id, if: 'current_step == "class"'
```

## Controller

```
def update
    ...
    if @user.update(params)
#this evaluates to true since the current_step == "school", and school_id is present  
      @user.update(current_step: @user.next_step)
#I am unable to update the current_step, because current_step == "class" now, and the class_id is missing
      redirect_to registration_path(@user)
    else
      render "show"
    end
  end
end
```

So basically, what is the best way to update the current_step of the object, without it triggering validation? Or is there a better way to do this? I have a feeling that I need to move the current_step object out of the model and into a session, but I would like to keep it attached to the model if possible and clean.

Comment: Please take a look at [`update_attribute`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute) or [`update_columns`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something as simple as:

```
@user.update_attribute(:current_step, @user.next_step)
```

This will not trigger validations. Or you can push it into params hash like this:

```
params[:user][:current_step] = @user.next_step
```

and then do update:

```
@user.update(params)
```

This way you will limit yourself with 1 mysql query

An alternative for this is to store current_step in the session, if you want to look at it.

There is a nice rails cast on that:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms

Comment: Worked great thank you, did not realize there was an update_attribute (singular)